# How to request.method==PUT, POST on Django rest framework

Tags: curl, django-models, request, django-rest-framework, updatemodel

I am working with Django REST Framework serializing some models.

This is my `Match`  serializer model

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    field = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Field.objects.all(),slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Match
        fields = ('url', 'id', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'field', 'match_date', 'check_match_away_team', 'status_challenge', 'home_team_players_accept', 'away_team_players_accept', 'home_team_players_cancel', 'away_team_players_cancel', 'fichaje_players_match',)
```

In the `Match` model, the fields are such as follow:

- `home_team`, `away_team` attributes, are a `ForeingKey`'s to my `Team` model and not null
- `field` attribute is a `ForeignKey` too and not null.
- `status_challenge` is a `CharField` and not null
- `home_team_players_accept`, `away_team_players_accept`, `home_team_players_cancel`, `away_team_players_cancel`, and `fichaje_players_match` fields have a `ManyToMany` relationship to my custom `User` model. These were defined of this way in my `Match` model such as follow:

  ```
  class Match(models.Model):

      home_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          related_name='home_team_players_accept',
          blank=True,)

      away_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          related_name='away_team_players_accept',
          blank=True,)

      home_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          related_name='home_team_players_cancel',
          blank=True,)

      away_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          related_name='away_team_players_cancel',
          blank=True,)

      fichaje_players_match = models.ManyToManyField(
          settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
          related_name='fichaje_players_match',
          blank=True,)
  ```

My situation is when I am update one Match object via curl and through my mobile iOS app client, I have the following case:

I have a record Match of this way:

```
{
    "url": "https://myserver/api/matchs/29/",
    "id": 29,
    "home_team": "Manchester United",
    "away_team": "Sempiternos FC",
    "field": "Joga Bonito",
    "match_date": "2017-01-02T09:00:05Z",
    "check_match_away_team": true,
    "status_challenge": "Aceptado",
    "home_team_players_accept": [
        "paoc",
        "nuevo"
    ],
    "away_team_players_accept": [
        "mike",
        "giraldoesteban"
    ],
    "home_team_players_cancel": [
        "erick"
    ],
    "away_team_players_cancel": [
        "Bluse"
    ],
    "fichaje_players_match": [
        "Oliver"
    ]
}
```

When I have PUT operation via `curl` tool command to this record, perform my update just in the `status_challenge` field changing their value from `Aceptado` to `Pendiente` this update PUT is done, with my `home_team_players_accept`, `away_team_players_accept`, `home_team_players_cancel`, `away_team_players_cancel`, and `fichaje_players_match` array fields are set to blank or empty, their values are remove:

```
bgarcial@elpug : ~
[0] % curl -X PUT https://myserver/api/matchs/29/ -d "home_team=Manchester United&away_team=Sempiternos FC&field=Joga Bonito&match_date=2017-01-2T09:00:05Z&check_match_away_team=true&status_challenge=Pendiente" 
{"url":"https://myserver/api/matchs/29/","id":29,"home_team":"Manchester United","away_team":"Sempiternos FC","field":"Joga Bonito","match_date":"2017-01-02T09:00:05Z","check_match_away_team":true,"status_challenge":"Pendiente","home_team_players_accept":[],"away_team_players_accept":[],"home_team_players_cancel":[],"away_team_players_cancel":[],"fichaje_players_match":[]}%           
bgarcial@elpug : ~
[0] %
```

Currently my Match record is of this way:

[image]

This also occur when I perform the update via my mobile application which consume the API

I try work with the case when `request.method == 'PUT'` of this way in my viewset:

```
class MatchViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Match.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MatchSerializer
    filter_fields = ('home_team','away_team', 'status_challenge', 'fichaje_players_match', )

    @api_view(['PUT'])
    def match_detail(request, pk):
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            serializer = MatchSerializer()
            if serializer.is_valid():
                serializer.save()
                return Response(serializer)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And the result is the same, I unknown in this moment how to address this situation and [the guide](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#browser-enhancements) is not enough clear for me

How to can I update the `status_challenge` field of the model serializer `Match` without that the players field referenced above stayed in blank or remove their content?

---

**UPDATE**

The transitivity is of some way such as follow:

There is my custom `User` model

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ... other attributes ...   

    team = models.ForeignKey(
        'games_information.Team',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name='Equipo en el que juega',    
    )
```

The `User` serializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, existe un fichaje con este nombre de usuario')])
    email = serializers.EmailField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, alguien ya ha sido fichado con este correo electrónico')])

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password is not None:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        for attr, value in validated_data.items():
            if attr == 'password':
                instance.set_password(value)
            else:
                setattr(instance, attr, value)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'first_name','last_name',
                  'age', 'sex', 'photo', 'email', 'is_player', 'team',
                  'position', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser',
                  'is_player', 'weight', 'height', 'nickname',
                  'number_matches', 'accomplished_matches',
                  'time_available', 'leg_profile', 'number_shirt_preferred',
                  'team_support', 'player_preferred', 'last_login',)
```

The `Team` model have a `ManyToMany` field to `User` model:

```
class Team(models.Model):

    ... other fields ...

    players = models.ManyToManyField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name='players',
        blank=True,
    )
```

This is my `TeamSerializer`

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    name = serializers.CharField(validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=Team.objects.all(), message='Lo sentimos, ya existe un equipo con este nombre')])
    place_origin = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Field.objects.all(),slug_field='name')

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = ('url', 'name', 'image', 'players', 'modality', 'branch', 'category', 'category_name', 'place_origin', 'game_day',)
```

The Match model, have the `home_team_players_accept`, `away_team_players_accept`, `home_team_players_cancel`, `away_team_players_cancel` and `fichaje_players_match` fields, all in `ManyToMany` relationship with the `User` model (`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`)

```
class Match(models.Model):

       ... other fields ...
       STATUS_CHALLENGE_CHOICES = (
           (ACCEPTED_CHALLENGE, u'Aceptado'),
           (PENDING_CHALLENGE, u'Pendiente'),
           (CANCELLED_CHALLENGE, u'Cancelado'),
           (FICHAJE, u'Fichaje'),
       ) 
       status_challenge = models.CharField(
           choices=STATUS_CHALLENGE_CHOICES,
           max_length=40,
           default=True,
           blank=False,
           verbose_name='Estado del desafío'
        )
        home_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='home_team_players_accept',
            blank=True,)

        away_team_players_accept = models.ManyToManyField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='away_team_players_accept',
            blank=True,)

        home_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='home_team_players_cancel',
            blank=True,)

        away_team_players_cancel = models.ManyToManyField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='away_team_players_cancel',
            blank=True,)

        fichaje_players_match = models.ManyToManyField(
            settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
            related_name='fichaje_players_match',
            blank=True,)
```

This is my `Match` serializer:

```
class MatchSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        field = serializers.SlugRelatedField(queryset=Field.objects.all(),slug_field='name')

        class Meta:
            model = Match
            fields = ('url', 'id', 'home_team', 'away_team', 'field', 'match_date', 'check_match_away_team', 'status_challenge', 'home_team_players_accept', 'away_team_players_accept', 'home_team_players_cancel', 'away_team_players_cancel', 'fichaje_players_match',)
```

The inconvenient is that I described initially above. When I apply to update to Match endpoint record, in the field `status_challenge` the records in the `home_team_players_accept`, `away_team_players_accept`, `home_team_players_cancel`, `away_team_players_cancel` and `fichaje_players_match` fields are removed or set to blank

Comment: Could you add the serializer you're using ? The one you pasted would not return names in away_team_players_accept / away_team_players_accept /...

Comment: @Linovia I understandd that you tell me, but the serializer that I am using is the `MatchSerializer` class denoted in the beginning of my question. My `MatchSerializer` should return this attributes? is possible that I am doing something crazy or non sense ... I'll appreciate your support

Comment: Where does the section with `"away_team_players_accept": ["mike", "giraldoesteban"],` comes from ?

Comment: @Linovia I've been made one update to my question, specifying a few more about of my models and serializers involved in this situation.  I hope have understood your question and my apologies for this long update :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need partial update. PUT calls update() and PATCH calls partial_update().
The only difference is partial=True (PATCH) or partial=False (PUT). And you can set partial yourself when initializing the serializer in your views.

You can do it like in Django REST framework code (mixins.py), to perform partial updates with PUT:

```
def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['partial'] = True
    return super(YourCustomView, self).update(request, *args, **kwargs)
```